# Where to prevent HTML and script injection?

Tags: security, web-applications, language-agnostic, xss

In web applications in order to prevent HTML and script injection, should I escape user input:

1. On the client before sending it to the server.
2. On the server before saving it to the database (on which layer - business, data, web interface?).
3. On the server before sending it back to the client.
4. On the client before rendering.
5. All or some of the above.

?

Comment: Server Side validation is regarded more secure than client side. Use client side validation only for providing a good user interface and small security checks.

Answer (score 0):

Escape all input at point of entry, also use a class based structure. If you have functions which are reused often, also escape here.

Any point where the server gets information from the client is a vunerable point, so protect each one you find.

Answer (score -1):

You should treat all user input as dirty and do either:

1. Validate input strictly (only white listed values accepted)
2. Validate input loosely every time you intend to use it. This means you validate it for sql injections when you insert it into the db **everytime**, not just the first time. This means that if you get something from the db which was once user input, the next time you re-insert it into the db, you must still treat it as user input as validate it. And when you push it to the client you need to validate it as client safe (xss, js, html, css) as well.